# Getting Exception faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Client

Tags: java, soap, axis

I am using axis1. While applying command cryptic for my soap I am getting an exception like below. Below are the details.

```
[ERROR] 2011-05-06 09:23:56,073 [MyAmeadeusTest] (MyAmeadeusTest.java:crypticCommand:278)
 11|Session|

AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Client
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString:  11|Session|
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace: 11|Session|
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:601)
```

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do one of two things:

1) Look on the web server that your SOAP requests are going to.  In those logs you'll probably find the Exception being thrown on that side that is turning into the AxisFault.

2) Use something like WireShark to trace the HTTP traffic.  Although this won't give you a lot of information beyond what you already have, it will prove that the AxisFault is basically a client-side representation of an Exception thrown on the server side.

The stack trace you get in this instance (i.e., from SoapFaultBuilder) is entirely misleading, as it's the stack trace of the code that is creating a client-side representation of the server error rather than the server-side stack trace showing the actual problem.